# python win32 com closing itunes

Tags: python, com, itunes, win32com

Launching itunes with win32com is easy.

```
try:
    itunes = win32com.client.GetActiveObject("iTunes.Application")
except:
    itunes = win32com.client.Dispatch("iTunes.Application")
```

How do I terminate the itunes I launched?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just call `Quit` method.

```
itunes.Quit()
```